# Excel - Send a msgbox if all the checkboxes (ActiveX) are unchecked

Tags: excel, checkbox, activex, vba

I'm trying to make the macro send a msgbox in case any checkbox of the activesheet (ActiveX) is checked.

I dont know why, but when I run the macro it jumps the line "x = x + 1" even if I have a checkbox checked...

Can someone help me?

```
Private Sub adecoagrobox1_Click()


If adecoagrobox1.Value = True Then
    On Error Resume Next
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Comps_pivot").PivotTables("compspivot1").AddDataField Sheets("Comps_pivot").PivotTables( _
    "compspivot1").PivotFields("Adecoagro"), "Adecoagro ", xlSum
Else
    On Error Resume Next
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Comps_pivot").PivotTables("compspivot1").PivotFields("Adecoagro "). _
    Orientation = xlHidden

End If

Dim control as OLEObject
Dim x as integer
x = x + 1

  For Each control In ActiveSheet.OLEObjects
If TypeName(control.Object) = "Checkbox" And control.Object.Value = 1 Then
 x = x + 1
End If
Next control

If x = 0 Then
MsgBox ("You must select at least one option")
On Error Resume Next
adecoagrobox1.Value = True
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Comps_pivot").PivotTables("compspivot1").AddDataField Sheets("Comps_pivot").PivotTables( _
    "compspivot1").PivotFields("Adecoagro"), "Adecoagro ", xlSum

End If


End Sub
```

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Remove the `On Error Resume Next` statements and see what error you are encountering

Comment: And note that your test for `If x = 0 Then` is pointless because you have an `x = x + 1` immediately after the `Dim x as integer` (hmmm, why isn't the `i` in `integer` in upper-case - the IDE should automatically change that?!?!) which means that `x` will always be at least `1`.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the quick answer! 

When I run the macro, it always jump the x = x + 1...So x always equals 0.

It does not read when a checkbox is checked...x=0 means that no checkbox is checked and it should shows the msgbox

Comment: If it is jumping that original `x = x + 1` (the one that is not inside the `If`, and is not related to any control) then something is seriously wrong with your file.

Comment: The `x = x + 1` **within** the loop is being skipped because `"Checkbox"` should be `"CheckBox"` and `= 1` should be `= True`, but that doesn't explain why that original `x = x + 1` is being skipped.

Comment: Can you put a `MsgBox "Before x=x+1, x is " & x` just before the original `x = x + 1` and a `MsgBox "After x=x+1, x is " & x` just after it.  It would be interesting to see whether it is somehow `-1` before the statement and being incremented to `0`, or whether it was `0` at the start and the increment isn't happening.

Comment: You got it! that is exactly how i got the macro right

Answer (score 1):

Here is what happens

```
Dim x as integer
```

The default value for an integer is 0. So X is set as 0.

```
x = x + 1
```

Immediately you are incrementing and setting it as 1.

```
If x = 0 Then
MsgBox ("You must select at least one option")
```

So the above condition is never met

remove the line x = x + 1 just after declaration and then try

Comment: Hey! thanks for the quick answer! My intention is if there any checkbox checked in the activesheet (total of 9), x should be higher than zero.
If there is no checkbox checked, x should be zero and it should send a msgbox.
the problem is that even when i have checkboxes checked, it is reading x as 0.

Answer (score 0):

It was a very silly mistake...

Instead of the B of CheckBox has to be in Capital letters...so CheckBox instead of Checkbox

and also true instead of 1

two mistakes in the same line

Comment: But that still doesn't explain why the first `x = x + 1` is being ignored.

Comment: @Leonardo Marcondes, If this has solved your problem, are you able to accept your answer so that this thread is marked "solved" and other do not spend time unnecessarily going through your problem! Thanks.

Comment: @BharatAnand The problem is that this **doesn't** solve the issue.  There were **two** lines of code that were being skipped for some reason and the change proposed in this answer only explains the reason for **one** of the lines being skipped.

Comment: Ok, I would like to recreate to attempt solve this. Can someone explain what is 'adecoagro'? How is this code being invoked? The problem statement mentions "... in case any checkbox of the activesheet ...", however, this code seems to be written for a specific checkbox named adecoagro. Am I right?

Comment: @BharatAnand The relevant part of the code is from the `Dim control as OLEObject` down to the `If x = 0 Then`.  The two `x = x + 1` statements were being skipped, and thus `x` was always `0`.  The OP and I both came up with the reason for the one inside the `If` statement being skipped, but there seems no reason why the one directly after the `Dim x as integer` to be skipped.